# Запрет прямого доступа

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, сервер

Имеется самописная cms, главный файл index.php, далее в нем подгружается iframe с нужными проектами (сайт), которые находятся в папке

```
/project/[имя проекта]/[страничка.php]
```

Управление происходит через GET запросы, строка имеет вид:

```
domen.ru/?project=name&page=index.php
```

C папки `/project/` стоит редирект на главную. НО в исходном коде можно посмотреть ссылку фрейма и открыть напрямую

```
/project/[имя проекта]/[страничка.php]
```

Задача: хотелось бы сделать «единую точку входа» (не получается) чтобы все запросы по пути `/project/[что то там]` перекидывались на `index.php` и нельзя было открыть проекты на прямую.

Если прописать просто `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]`
то в самом фрейме тоже происходит перенаправление контента, что не приемлемо(

Comment: Очень просто - перенести каталог project на уровень выше index.php

Comment: и что это даст? помоему что выше что ниже - никакой разницы!

Comment: И какие же по-вашему будут ссылки на файлы, если каталог будет на уровень выше index.php?)

Comment: может я вас не правильно понял, а возможно и вы меня.
я хотел бы запретить доступ к файлам напрямую.
а из под фрейма бы можно было грузить.
если расположим папку ниже, то что изменится?

Comment: Хотя да, я похоже неправильно вопрос понял. Если вы хотите, чтобы страница во фрейме открывалась, а без фрейма не открывалась, то это технически невозможно, потому что фрейм - такая же обыкновенная страница

Comment: я так и думал :(
тогда как можно реализовать мою задумку?
пробовал сначала не фреймом, а через ajax, но тогда грузится только тело странички, а все css js и картинки странички не подгружаются так как имеют якобы не правильный url (прописано /name.css а файл получается лежит /project/name/name.css)

Comment: Можно (и, скорее всего, лучше) ajax, но тогда, конечно, нужно сами отдаваемые страницы слегка переписать, чтобы они не отдавали нерабочих относительных ссылок на эти самые картинки. А с ифреймами максимум, что можно сделать, добавить на js проверку уже *после* загрузки страницы, что страница во фрейме, а если нет, то вырубить страницу. Но это легко обойти если очень захотеть, так что бессмысленно)

Comment: 1. код проекта менять нельзя, он чистый. когда проект готов, то в 1 клик архив с этим проектом отправляется на почту. поэтому не подходит.
2. это тоже не подходит, так как проверку на js нужно подключать именно в файле проекта. что опять не допустимо. этот код передается клиенту, там не должно быть мусора.

поэтому хочется на уровне сервера сделать такую проверку. если есть фрейм или какой-нибуть токен/переменная, то разрешать. иначе нет.

Comment: Эм, если код проекта менять нельзя, тогда гарантированно никак

Comment: а можно ли в htaccess заменять запрос вида "/project/..". на "?progect=..."

Answer (score 1):

А что если сделать чтобы projects открывались только по токену, который может генерировать только index.php. Если токена нет - редирект.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @Kromster это больше похоже на вариант решения, чем на новый вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin промазал, сорри

Comment: @Kromster да, это и есть вариант решения. Собственно, так я и сделал пару лет назад с похожей задачей.